# Can't convert .obj files to the new .usdz format

Tags: augmented-reality, ios12, usdz

when trying to convert my .obj files to .usdz using command line, I can't find the generated file.

[Screenshot showing the command line is not generating the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSSJ7.png)

I got a message saying the file was generated with success, but there's no generated file at all. :(

What I've done so far:

- Updated my Xcode to Version 10.0 (10A255)
- Updated 'USD' path environment variables, following USDPYTHON documentation. (export PATH=$PATH:/USD
  export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/USD)
- Using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Any clues on any step I missing to successfully convert a model to .usdz?

Note: When using a 3rd party tool, like https://vectary.com for example, I'm able to convert my .obj model.

Thanks!